# Prevent popstate event running?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, dom-events

I'm using React, and react router, and I want it so when a user is on certain sections of the website a confirm box shows up, tell them if they left the page they could lose some progress. Currently I have a `onbeforeunload` event that handles when the user refreshes or closes the window, however with the browser's back button, i have to use `onpopstate`. using the code shown below the confirm box shows up, but the page still loads to the previous state.

```js
this.currentListener = function(event) {
  if (event.type === 'popstate') {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();

    var leave =  confirm(message);
    console.log(leave)
  } else {
    return message;
  }
};
window.onbeforeunload = this.currentListener;
window.onhashchange = this.currentListener;
```

Comment: Is the event a React synthetic event?

Comment: [No.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onpopstate)

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: converting the component into a mixin. Per React docs, multiple lifecycle calls will result in all being called. http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#mixins.

Have you looked at using a static willTransitionFrom method on the component? Something like this...

```js
var PreventLeavingMixin = {
  statics: {
    willTransitionFrom: function(transition, component) {
      //you have access to your component's state and functions with the component param
      if (component.someMethod()) {
        //transition can make the navigation stop
        if (!confirm('Are you sure you want to leave?')) {
          transition.abort();
        }
      }
    }
  }
};

var MyComponent = React.createClass({
  mixins: [PreventLeavingMixin],
  render: function() {
    return: ...
  }
});
```

Note -- you may need to have to have an `onAbort()` method specified on the `Router.create()`;

More on Router Transition here: [http://rackt.github.io/react-router/#Route Handler](http://rackt.github.io/react-router/#Route%20Handler)

Comment: Well currently the code is in a mixin, that is spread to many components.

Comment: Do I still need an `onAbort`?

Comment: I actually don't think so. I had to do that for one of my scenarios to handler a server side redirect, so that was probably still fresh on my mind.

Comment: I won't be able to verify the answer till Monday. But looks good to me.

Comment: This is helpful, but it only works for transitions initiated by the app.  It doesn't work for the user clicking the back button or entering a new URL manually.

Comment: You need to combined ``willTransitionFrom`` with the ``onbeforeunload`` event described by Aaronepower.

Comment: Hmm.. it works for me. Can you update your code on here?